# date one day ago when consume rest angular 6 and Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, angular, rest, spring-boot

I have an attribute of the type: "Date" in java in a class and from the fron (angle 6) I sent a date with the format "dd / MM / yyyy". The problem is that when I receive it, it arrives with the day before I send it from the front.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Fecha</label>
            <input class="form-control" #fecha="ngModel" name="fecha" [(ngModel)]="pedidoCompra.fecha" type="date"
              required>
            <span class="help-block text-red" *ngIf="!fecha.valid && fecha.touched">La fecha es obligatoria
              <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle "></i>
            </span>
          </div>
```

Angular:

```
create(pedidoCompra: PedidoCompra): Observable<PedidoCompra> {
pedidoCompra.fecha = new Date((new Date(pedidoCompra.fecha)).getTime() + (60*60*24*1000));
return this.http.post<PedidoCompra>(this.url + 'pedido-compra', pedidoCompra, { headers: this.httpHeaders });
```

}

Java Class:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "fecha")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fecha;
```

Comment: It's just a guess (could you provide some examples?) but did you define a timezone? If not at least one of the dates might be interpreted as UTC which might have quite some offset from the timezone you're in.

Comment: Are you using `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? Can't you use `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: I am using java.util.Date

Comment: Moment.js is a great library to overcome timezone problems, its also supported by a lot of plugins (like angular material). https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I solved it in the following way:

    `this.date = new Date((new Date(this.date)).getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));`

Try with "moment", but I had no luck

Comment: Now if I solved it in a better way, I think that's fine
 `this.date= new Date(moment(this.date).toDate());`